# Rails loop not generationg grids

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a loop that iterates through a list of stories but it's generating one row per story and not 3 columns. What am I missing?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <% @stories.each do |story| %>
        <h2><%= story.name.titleize %></h2>
        <%= image_tag story.pictures.first.image(:medium).to_s, class: "img-responsive" %>
        <%= link_to "View Story", story_path(story) %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Assuming your using bootstrap.  You're nesting all of your information within the single column,  not creating three columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're placing the each loop in the wrong place. Try something like:

```
<div class="row">
  <% @stories.each do |story| %>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <%= content_tag :h2, story.name.titleize %>
      <%= image_tag story.pictures.first.image(:medium).to_s, class: "img-responsive" %>
      <%= link_to "View Story", story_path(story) %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: I had tried putting the "col-md-4" below the loop but it wasn't working until I saw where you placed the </div> before <% end %>. That did the trick. Thanks a lot DaniG2K.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look to each_slice

```
@stories = [story1, story2, story3, story4, story5, story6, story7, story8]
@stories.each_slice(3).to_a
#=> [[story1, story2, story3], [story4, story5, story6], [story7, story8]]
```

I think you can try this:

```
<% @stories.each_slice(3).to_a.each do |row_stories| %>
    <div class="row">
        <% row_stories.each do |story| %>
            <div class="col-md-4">
            <%= content_tag :h2, story.name.titleize %>
                <%= image_tag story.pictures.first.image(:medium).to_s, class: "img-responsive" %>
                <%= link_to "View Story", story_path(story) %>
                </div>
        <% end %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This is new to me. No idea how it works but I'm gonna play with the code to see what it does. Thanks for the answer djothefou.